# odoo server error while opening a lead,odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

i have used a domian rule :
['|',('user_id','=',user.id),('message_partner_ids','child_of',[user.commercial_partner_id.id])]

under "Personal lead" record rule and object is "Lead/Opportunity"
and while clicking on a lead as user i get an error:
raise ValueError("Invalid field %r in leaf %r" % (left, str(leaf)))

ValueError: Invalid field 'user_id' in leaf ""

i know user_id does not belong to mail.followers model and so i see this error. should i change my domain rule?

my prior requirement is my users to see both
-Leads that has them as salesperson 
-Leads that they follow but has different salesperson

above mentioned domain rule does satisfy that requirement , it lists all the leads but opening them gives me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my prior requirement is my users to see both -Leads that has them as
>   salesperson -Leads that they follow but has different salesperson

You do not need to add a rule, this functionality is already supported.
The owner of the lead or someone who has access to it can add them as followers on the bottom by clicking the Add Followers and they will be able to see the document.

[image]

Comment: hello, thank you... but all the followers will see only the emails or messages sent to them by the salesperson or any other follower, but they will not be able to see all the leads, listed under "leads" option in sales app.  i already got a solution for my problem, if you want to apply that as well , let me know:)  Thank you for your comment.